# For any integer a and c such that $a \gt c$, is it true that at least one integer in the range $[a, a+c]$ will have a prime factor greater than $c$

Tags: prime-numbers

For any integer a and c such that $a \gt c$, is it true that at least
one integer in the range $[a, a+c]$ will have a prime factor greater
than $c$? If this happens to be true, what about if an integer in the range will have a prime factor greater than $2c$?
This is for a personal project that I'm working on, but I don't think this could be used in many situations. I'm hoping that there is an easy proof or counterexample for this, or that there is already an existing theorem that directly or indirectly proves this.

Comment: google Bertrands postulate. Then consider that if $a > c$ so then $a+c > 2c$

Comment: @flea, that will show there's a prime between $c$ and $a+c$, but why should it be between $a$ and $a+c$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Where did I ever say it would?

Comment: @flea, of course you didn't, but you've left OP to figure out how a prime between $c$ and $a+c$ implies a prime factor exceeding $c$ between $a$ and $a+c$.